# Regex uniform pattern requirements

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying to parse parcel numbers with regex and have run into some issues. I started with this:

```
r'(?<=[":#][\s\n])(\d{2}[-:\s]*\d{2}[-:\s]*\d{3}[-:\s]*\d{3}(?:\-{1}\d{4})?)'
```

with the look behind to make sure I didn't return a phone number or internal file number of 10 or 14 digit length by accident. Then it turned out that one listing might contain several parcel number (up to 40+) separated by any number of chars (whitespace, and, /, &, etc.). So then I chopped off the look behind to deal with this like so:

```
r'\d{2}[-:\s]*\d{2}[-:\s]*\d{3}[-:\s]*\d{3}(?:[-:\s]*\d{4}$)?'
```

But then on an example containing:

# 22-33-155-003 NKA 22-33-155-009 ...... H/W # 41877 1021690 UPAXLP

Which returned:

```
['22-33-155-009', '22-33-155-003', '1877 102169']
```

I have tried adding `^` to the beginning and `$` to the end to prevent the last bit (41877 1021690 UPAXLP) from returning '1877 102169', but then it returns nothing.

Each listing is from a different source which has different formats for showing parcel numbers, the only sure fire way is to identify 10 digit patterns with possible characters (-,/, SPACE, etc.) separating and using the look behind/ahead to ensure it is in fact a parcel number.

My questions are:

1) How can I maintain the look ahead/behind while accounting for the possibility of several parcels separated by several possible chars?

2) How can I enforce that if a separating character is used, that it is used the entire way through? So `12-34-567-890` or `12 34 567 890` and not `1234 567890` or `12-34:567 890`, which would prevent the last example shown above.

3) Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What's the parcel number format?

Comment: @PauloMendes depends on the county (my function takes the county name as the second argument), but in the example above: 2 digits [0 or 1 separating character] 2 digits [0 or 1 separating character] 3 digits [0 or 1 separating character] 3 digits [0 or 1 separating character] [possible 4 digit end sequence]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce identical separation characters using lookbehind:

```
r"""
\d{2}(?P<separator>[-:\s]?)
\d{2}(?P=separator)
\d{3}(?P=separator)
\d{3}(?:(?P=separator)\d{4})?"""
```

This regex matches the pattern you described, I think. I took your own regex, added the separator feature, and removed the '$'. I think the '$' was gumming up the works...

Comment: it seems to just return the separator instead of the pattern. I tried wrapping the entire thing in parentheses but then it returns the pattern and the separator: `[('22-33-155-003', '-'), ('22-33-155-009', '-')]`

Comment: Apparently named groups must be captured, I am guessing I need to use python to iterate over the findall results and just take the 0th item from each tuple?

Comment: Yes, I think that's the best way to do it. Maybe there's some way to select just number, but finding it doesn't seem to be worth the trouble.